# Weird casting issue in Java

Tags: java, generics, casting

This might look pretty dumb though but, how can I cast this:

```
Expression<?> myExpression = ...
```

to this so that it fits into the given parameter:

```
<Y extends java.lang.Comparable<? super Y>> gt(Expression<? extends Y> parameter)
```

I have no clue how to solve this though..

Comment: How are you calling the method qt?

Comment: Do you mean that the second code block works fine, and that you only want to modify the first block?

Comment: What is the context of this? What is `Y`?

Comment: You mean, how to get from `Expression<?>` to `Expression<? extends Y>`? I think we may need to know what `myExpression` is being set to. Are you sure that your `<?>` does, in fact, extend `Y`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest is to use erasure (which will give you a warning you can turn off)

```
gt((Expression) myExpression);
```

Comment: Aaaah.. of course, I didn't think about the most simple way ha!

Answer (score 0):

You must declare myExpression as an Expression where X is of class Y or a subtype of Y, as requested by your method "gt".

Or, cast it to the required type before calling the method, but you'd get a compiler warning then.